# add menu page in loop menu order

Tags: php, plugin-development, admin-menu, add-menu-page

I have a function that creates custom admin menu items from an array of child pages.

They seem to get returned in `alpha-numeric` order.

I would like them to get sorted by the `page order` set in `page attributes`.

I have searched online, but can't seem to find an easy solution. Before writing a script to do this manually I was wanting to see if anyone has some input on a `wp_core` method that might make this easier.

Here is the current code for reference:

```
public function create_custom_menu() {
    $menuArray = $this->get_top_level_pages();
        foreach ($menuArray as $key => $value) {
            add_menu_page( 
                $value->post_title, 
                $value->post_title, 
                'manage_options', 
                $value->post_name.'-admin-page', 
                array( $this, 'create_admin_page'), 
                'dashicons-admin-home' ,
                6
            );
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok it took me a while, but I think I have it. I had to use usort. I also included the code for the `get_top_level_pages()` method.

```
    $my_wp_query = new WP_Query();
    $all_wp_pages = $my_wp_query->query(array('post_type' => 'page', 'posts_per_page' => '-1'));
    $top_level_pages =  get_page_by_title('Locations');
    $menuArray = get_page_children( $top_level_pages->ID, $all_wp_pages );
    function compareOrder($a, $b) {
        return $a->menu_order - $b->menu_order;
    }
    usort($menuArray, 'compareOrder');
```

or, as I found out later I could just replace the last value in my array with:

```
public function create_custom_menu() {
    $menuArray = $this->get_top_level_pages();
        foreach ($menuArray as $key => $value) {
            add_menu_page( 
                $value->post_title, 
                $value->post_title, 
                'manage_options', 
                $value->post_name.'-admin-page', 
                array( $this, 'create_admin_page'), 
                'dashicons-admin-home' ,
                $value->page_attributes->menu-order
            );
      }
}
```

or even easier, I could have just added `'orderby'=>'menu_order'` to my query initially.